# Sticky posts not showing when using category filter

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to show a specific category post on my home page and in which 1 post is sticky that will appear first but its not working.

I have noticed when I try to show all posts, then sticky post shows first. When I try to show a specific category then its not showing first.

Here is my code:

````
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => intval($blogtoShow), 
               'post_status'=>'publish', 
               'post_type'=>'post',
               'cat' => $cattoShow, 
               'orderby'=>'date', 
               'post__in' => $sticky);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();```
````

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the following:

`ignore_sticky_posts` (boolean) – ignore post stickiness (available since version 3.1, replaced caller_get_posts parameter). **false (default): move sticky posts to the start of the set.** true: do not move sticky posts to the start of the set.

If you're using a pre-made theme the default might have been modified.

You should add this to your arguments array: `'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0`.
A comma should separate each arguments. (Not tested but should work)

More info on the worpress query: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

**----------**
**EDIT 1.1:** I think you need to display a specific template for the sticky (as it's not considered a normal post). At the begining of your loop can you try the following?

```
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'      => 3,
    'post__in'            => $sticky,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $sticky[0] ) {
    // insert sticky template...
} else {
    // insert posts template...
}
```

Comment: i also try this ``` 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0 ``` but stil not working

Comment: Edited my answer, can you try the following from `EDIT 1.1`?